# Make visible single View in RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, view, visibility

I have a RelativeLayout which contains a LinearLayout containing 2 buttons. I would like to make those buttons visible without making the whole RelativeLayout or LinearLayout visible. While debugging, the button's getVisibility reports visible and getLocationOnScreen returns the correct placement but I can't see them. Here is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/edit_div_element"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/full_popup_element"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:clickable="false">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/close_edit"
        android:src="@drawable/view_edge_promotion_close_icon"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tint="@color/uniform_style_blue"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"/>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/popup_name_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/close_edit"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/popup_name_label"
            android:text="@string/popup_name_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_fixed_16" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/popup_name"
            android:hint=""
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/marginSmall" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popup_assignment_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/edit_assignment_label"
        android:layout_below="@id/popup_name_container"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/popup_assignment_label"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        >

      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/popup_assignment_recycler"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:clickable="false"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_1"
            android:text="@string/clear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/popup_assignment_recycler"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:background="@color/uniform_style_blue"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:background="@color/uniform_style_blue"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm setting visibility with

```
Button mBtn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
mBtn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Button mBtn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn_2);
mBtn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

I've also tried defining the RelativeLayout's visibility as INVISIBLE in the xml, still no luck.

Is it possible to just show the buttons? I'm stumped, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: It it not possible to have an invisible parent ViewGroup with a visible child View. So you need to redesign your layout or (if you leave it the way it is) you'll have to individually toggle the visibility of the ImageView, the RecyclerView, the *popup_assignment_label* TextView and the LinearLayout containing the EditText

Comment: Bummer, but great to know, thanks! Is it possible to have the button views outside of the layout, and put them at a fixed position on the screen relative to the relativelayout they're in now?

Comment: The height of the RelativeLayout will vary e.g. with the number and/ or size of items in the RecyclerView, so the position of the Buttons (which seems to be aligned to the bottom line of the RecyclerView) will have to vary as well (else you can simply set a top margin for the buttons). You *can* try to keep track of changes in the size of the RelativeLayout and each time set the Button position accordingly but IMO this is much more trouble than simply toggling the visiblility of six different Views as required by your app's business logic.

Comment: I see. My recyclerview is horizontal and has a set width, so I thought that may be straightforward. My concern with toggling visibility is, won't all of those elements show up, even if for a brief moment? To be clear, you're suggesting, a call to relativelayout.setVisibility(VISIBLE) and then toggling all of its child views to GONE? Again, thanks for the help - I've been stuck on this for too long!

Comment: If you're talking about setting all the child Views to GONE I'm wondering where the buttons really should show up. (Until now, I thought you wanted them to have a right margin of 180 dp and an y position dpending on the RecyclerView.) Maybe a picture would help to clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You have buttons placed inside the layout. If the whole parent is invisible, all the child views are invisible too. If you want to show only buttons, you have to make your relative layout visible, your linear layout visible, and then make your buttons visible. You can also hide all other content of your layout (make invisible) if you do not wanna show it.

Consider parent-child views as boxes. Your buttons - are small boxes, which are placed inside of other, bigger box, which is parent, linear layout. You cannot open small boxes without opening the large (parent) box first.

Comment: Thanks, I got as much from 0x0nosugar's comment. Is it possible to have the button views outside of the layout, and put them at a fixed position on the screen relative to the relativelayout they're in now?